# Concatinating results from Apply on groups in groupby dataframe in Python pandas library

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I've written:
`df.groupby(keys).apply(function)`

the function both filters the data by value and resamples by date for each group.

df input form is like
string1 string2 datetime val1 val2

key is like ["string1","string2"]

output should be like:
datetime  (val of "string1", val of "string2")...datetime  (val of "string1", val of "string2")...
where each string1,string2 is the corresponding column values under string1 and string2 above.

If i run this function as a for loop such as
`for name, group in grouped_result:`

I can easily concat the results by column, however using apply does something wonky with the results

FOR LOOP METHOD HERE:

```
keys = ["C/A","UNIT","SCP","STATION"]
grouped_df = df.groupby(keys)
list_of_groups = []
for name, group in grouped_df:
    new_df = group[["DATETIME","ENTRIES"]].set_index("DATETIME")  
    timeseries = (new_df - new_df.shift(1)).dropna()
    timeseries[timeseries["ENTRIES"] < 0] = 0
    timeseries[timeseries["ENTRIES"] > 5000] = 0
    new_timeseries = timeseries.resample('D',how='sum') #.reset_index()
    new_timeseries.columns = [name]
    list_of_groups.append(new_timeseries)
turnstile_counts_by_day = pd.concat(list_of_groups,axis=1)
```

APPLY METHOD BELOW:

```
def tester(group):
    new_df = group[["DATETIME","ENTRIES"]].set_index("DATETIME")
    timeseries = (new_df - new_df.shift(1)).dropna()
    timeseries[timeseries["ENTRIES"] < 0] = 0
    timeseries[timeseries["ENTRIES"] > 5000] = 0
    new_timeseries = timeseries.resample('D',how='sum') #.reset_index()
    new_timeseries.columns = [tuple(group.values[0][0:4])]
    return new_timeseries

keys = ["string1","string2"]
freddy = df.groupby(keys).apply(tester)
```

This appends the apply results underneath one another, instead of as columns, creating a really huge table. Is there a way to concat the applied results?

ref [groupby.GroupBy.apply documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html)

```
the result looked like
     res1  res2 res3
res1   1    nan  nan
res2  nan    1   nan
res3  nan   nan   1
```

where each res match are the summed values

I would like the result to be:

```
res1  res2  res3
  1     1     1
  .
  .
  ...
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: From your question it is rather difficult to infer what exactly you are trying to do. Maybe a little more code would make it easier for us.

Comment: i hope it is clearer now. I've edited the question thanks